# Can't show that these matrices are diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Consider that for each $n \times n$ (possibly complex) matrix, $A_{k}$, $0 \leq k \leq m$, we have that
\begin{align}
A_{0}A_{k} &= kA_{k}, \qquad 1 \leq k \leq m
\end{align}
and suppose that
\begin{align}
\sum \limits_{k=1}^{m} \text{rank}(A_{k}) = \text{rank}(A_{0}).
\end{align}
Show that $A_{0}$ is diagonalizable.

I want to show that $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ can be written as a sum of (non-generalized) eigenspaces of $A_{0}$.  I want to use the spectral theorem to try to do this.  However, I can't seem to show it any way, so if the spectral theorem doesn't work, then I am open to other methods.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Note that each (non-zero) column of $A_k$ must be an eigenvector (corresponding to $k$) of $A_0$, since
$$
A_0 \pmatrix{v_1&v_2&\cdots&v_n} = \pmatrix{A_0 v_1&A_0 v_2&\cdots&A_0 v_n}
= \pmatrix{k v_1&k v_2&\cdots&k v_n}
$$

Comment: Let's phrase it this way: each $A_k$ gives you a $\text{rank}(A_k)$-dimensional eigenspace of $A_0$.  Put them all together, and you find a basis for $\mathbb R^n$ made out of the eigenvalues of $A_0$

Comment: None of these eigenvalues have degree more than $1$.  Where are you getting that from?  An $n \times n$ matrix is diagonalizable if and only if it has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, what more is there to this?

Comment: None of these eigenvectors, the ones you have mentioned in your original comment have degree more than one, however these may not be all of the eigenvectors of the matrix $A_{0}$.  I'm not saying you're wrong I'm just having trouble seeing why these eigenvectors represent all genuine and generalized eigenvectors of $A_{0}$, which is the necessary machinery (as far as I am aware) for the spectral theorem.

Comment: If the $m$ sum in the above problem was replaced with $n$, then I would agree.

Comment: An $n \times n$ matrix can have at most $n$ (linearly independent) eigenvectors.  rank$(A_0)$ of those are in the columns of $A_k$, and there are null$(A_0)$ in the kernel of $A_0$.  By the rank nullity theorem, we have $n$ total.

Comment: Oh, okay okay! Nice!

Comment: Thanks for all of your help and patience.

Comment: Not a problem; I probably should have been clearer about the kernel.  Also, I suppose it's worth checking: according to the question, is $k = 0$ a possibility?  I just realized you have two different inequalities in the question.

Comment: Well, $A_{0}A_{k} = kA_{k}$ for $1 \leq k \leq m$ however $0$ can still be an eigenvalue.

Comment: Ah, okay, then the steps here are valid.  Glad to help.